# a second insertion in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a problem when I do insert into a different collection within the same callback, sorry for my English is that of google translator

my models

```
var mongos = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongos.Schema;

var bodegas = new Schema({
    idmayor:String, 
    bodegas:String
});

exports.bodegas = mongos.model("bodega",bodegas);


var mongos = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongos.Schema;

var empleados = new Schema({
    idmayor:String,
    nombre:String,
    correo:String,
    contraseña:String,
    bodega:String,
    activa:Boolean
});

exports.empleados = mongos.model("empleado",empleados);
```

and my control

```
exports.ingrese = function (req, res, next) {
    var id = req.session.paentro.id;
    var nombre = req.body.nombre;
    var correoElectronico = req.body.correo;
    var bodega = req.body.bodega;

    var InfoNuevoEmpleado = {
        idmayor: id,
        nombre: nombre,
        correo: correoElectronico,
        contraseñ a: "",
        bodega: bodega,
        activa: false
    };

    var nuevoEmpleado = new madb.empleados(InfoNuevoEmpleado);
    nuevoEmpleado.save(soyanonima);

    function soyanonima(err, resultado) {
        if (err) {
            res.send('Ha ocurrido un error porfavor intentalo mas tarde');
        } else {
            console.log('se ha ingresado como: \n' + resultado);
            var titulo = 'Hola nuevo abministrador';
            var mensage = 'hola se te ha creado una cuenta en el <b>manejador de inventario</b> ' +
                'porfavor dirigete al enlase abjunto para cambiar la contraseña ' +
                '<a href="localhost:3000/empleado/' + resultado.id + '"> aqui </a>';
            correo.enviar(titulo, mensage, correoElectronico);

            var InfoBodega = {
                idmayor: resultado.id,
                bodega: resultado.bodega
            };

            var nuevaBodega = new bodega.bodegas(InfoBodega);
            console.log(InfoBodega);
            nuevaBodega.save(function () {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("hay jueputa echele agua");
                } else {
                    res.send("Guardado");
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is created when I try to insert a second time in another collection.

Comment: What is the error when the code tries to save the second time?

Comment: Make sure when using callbacks, you declare all parameters properly: `nuevaBodega.save(function () {` ===> `nuevaBodega.save(function (err, results) {`

Comment: after asking what I've noticed, but continued with error =S typeError  undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you trying to create an object with an undefined model, you have set the variable of bodega to be equal to req.body.bodega, where this value is probably a string. Then when you try to get bodegas of a string it's undefined why you get the error. Instead you should import the file where you have your model like this `var bodega_model = require('bodega.js')` and define your object with `var nuevaBodega = bodega_model.bodegas(infoBodega)`, this will work. Try to debug it by printing the bodega model to the console.

Good luck!

Comment: @soldat25 did this help any?